# Redirect from a html filename that returns a 404 error to a good url that goes to an actual page

Tags: javascript

Visitors to our site have been asked in print ads to go to an html page with a # in the name: http:/devsite.com/page#1.html.

As you know, everything after the # drops off, and visitors are sent to the 404 error page.

We want to redirect them to a page with a different name: http://devsite.com/page-1.html.

The only way I could figure out to do this is to use this javascript on the error page:

```
//gets everything after the hash character, including the hash character

var hashString = window.location.hash;

//takes the hash out of hashString, concatenates that onto the base url (S8TIGER-) and loads that into the window.

if ( hashString ) {
    hashString = hashString.slice(1);
    window.location = 'http://devsite.com/page-' + hashString;
    } else {
    document.write ("<h1>Error page</h1> <br />");
}
```

I wonder if there's a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's on the server side? Apache? IIS? PHP? ASP.Net?

Comment: Who owns the web-server? If you own it then you can modify your web server settings to redirect requests to that specific URL to another URL.

Comment: Thanks - the server is a LAMP stack server. I don't know who manages the server - it's a client's website. We are just developing some landing pages.

Answer (score 0):

Many shared hostings services have GUIs which allow you set URL redirects.

Otherwise, you could set a [301 redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) on an apache configuration file (i.e. httpd.conf):

```
 Redirect "/page" "http://example.com/page-1.html"
```

You will have to restart apache, which you may not be able to do manually on shared hosting, and you should not edit configuration files on a production server, especially if you don't know what you're doing.

Alternatively, you could make a folder called "page" in the server document root and place an index.php file in the page folder with the following code:

```
<?php
// 301 Moved Permanently
header("Location: /page-1.html",TRUE,301);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  However, php redirects won't work in this instance. Here's why - in the url, everything after the hash mark is not sent to the server - it goes to the browser. Hence, the javascript solution.

Comment: Hi Ann - I guess I'm a little unclear on the use case. Is this a redirect for a single page? You are correct that everything after the hash string isn't sent to the server, so the server would field a request for /page. If this is a static, one-off situation, you know that /page is supposed to be /page-1.html, the solutions I listed should work. The result would actually probably be /page-1.html#1.html, which isn't pretty but shouldn't be a problem, and should be faster than your JS on the 404 page. If you are trying to handle page#1.html and page#2.html, then I agree my answer will not work.

Comment: You're right about that. But unfortunately, there are about six pages that need this treatment. Thanks, however!